# How to set FS to eof?

Tags: bash, awk, eof

I want to read whole file not per lines. How to change field separator to eof-symbol?

I do:

```
awk "^[0-9]+∆DD$1[PS].*$" $(ls -tr)
```

$1 - param (some integer), .* - message that I want to print. There is a problem: message can contains \n. In that way this code prints only first line of file. How can I scan whole file not per lines?
Can I do this using awk, sed, grep? Script must have length <= 60 characters (include spaces).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean record separator, not field separator, with GNU awk you'd do:

```
gawk -v RS='^$' '{ print "<" $0 ">" }' file
```

Replace the print with whatever you really want to do and update your question with some sample input and expected output if you want help with that part too.

The portable way to do this, by the way, is to build up the record line by line and then process it in the END section:

```
awk '{rec = rec (NR>1?RS:"") $0} END{ print "<" rec ">" }' file
```

using `nf = split(rec,flds)` to create fields if necessary.

Comment: QQ: Wouldn't `RS= ` do something similar? `RS='^$'` terminates on a new line.

Comment: @jaypal no. `RS=` tells awk that contiguous empty lines separate records, so it's for reading a paragraph at a time, not the whole file as one record. `RS='^$'` does not terminate on a newline, it terminates on a start-of-string ('^') immediately followed by an end-of-string ('$'). Since gawk treats the input file as a string, it can only contain `^$` if the file is empty, so setting `RS="^$"` is setting RS to a value that cannot exist in a non-empty input file and so the whole file is read as a single record.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for the explanation. Makes complete sense now. +1